# Does an auto-aligning tripod exist?

Tags: tripod, auto-alignment

Say you want to photograph yourself. The hassle is always framing yourself inside the picture while wanting to walk all around the camera to take snapshots with different backgrounds. Does this exist, where a tripod with a camera mounted can automatically sense where you are and align the camera (with motors somehow integrated on the camera stand)? I can imagine that it could detect where you are if you clip a frequency emitting device or something on your head somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: What about something like the Logitech QuickCam Orbit? Instead of a moving tripod, the camera follows your movement.

Comment: That is cool, but I wanted it to be suitable to a regular-sized DSLR camera.

Comment: Sony party-shot does this and even follows the rule-of-thirds while composing: http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&partNumber=IPTDS1

Answer (score 5):

Motorised pan-tilt heads that will mount an SLR or similart are relatively common. Prices can be high. It would be a relatively simple matter to have one of these track a well defined target such as an IR LED.

Here is an [$130 motorized pan tilt head](http://www.adorama.com/images/300x300/BOMPH.jpg)

[image]

---

[Similar from Polaroid](http://cameradigitalstores.com/polaroid-automatic-motorized-pan-head-with-wireless-remote-control-for-the-sony-alpha-nex-5-nex-3-nex-5n-nex-7-nex-c3-dslr-a100-a200-a230-a290-a300-a330-a350-a380-a390-a450-a500-a560-slt-a33-slt-a55-slt-a65-slt-a77-slt-a35-a550-a700-a850-a900-digital-slr-)
Available [here - on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005UEN0PI) for $US65

[image]

Some details:

- AutoMatically Pans 120 Degrees (60 Degree to the left & 60 Degree To The Right Of Center) & Tilts 30 Degrees (15 up and 15 down from level)
- Includes 20ft Remote Sensor Cord & 20ft Extension Cord Allowing You To Place The Remote Sensor In Any Direction Up To 40ft Away
- Accepts Most Cameras & Camcorders <> Also Pan And Tilts Manually
  Motorized Head Operates On Household Current Or AA Batteries
- Controlled By Wireless, Infrared Transmitter

---

Oh Yes! Wow! ...... !
 Prices will be "more than you want to pay" (and then some)
[**Wow!**](http://www.mrmoco.com/blog/tag/lightweight-control/page/2/)

[Also wow](http://www.camerakings.co.uk/product_images/i/614/sr.head-4__22517_zoom.jpg) "only" GBP550